# How to delete foreign key record

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've got two tables `Employee` and `Address`. `Employee` is my main table and `Address` is a child table associated to `Employee` via the foreign key `AddressId`.

The records from `Address` are not deleted when I delete an `Employee` record. How I can rewrite my code to do so?

```
Employee:
  [Id](Primary Key)
  [FirstName] 
  [LastName]
  [Email]
  [AddressId] (Foreign Key -> Address.Id)
  [Code]

Address:
  [Id] (Primary Key)
  [Details]
  [State]
  [Country]
```

Here is my current code:

```
public bool DeleteEmployee(int id)
{
            using (var context=new EmployeeDBEntities())
            {
                var employee = context.Employee.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
               
                if (employee != null)
                {
                    context.Employee.Remove(employee);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Main table, another table , child table - employee, address - you could be clearer.

Comment: There are two tables

Comment: I know but which is main and which is child ? Also add your full table definitions.

Comment: There are two tables Employee and Address. Employee is main table with below fields and address is the child table associated to Employee Table with the foreign key AddressId. The record from Address Table doesn't gets deleted when I delete Employee Table records.
How I can rewrite the code

Comment: Employee is main and address is child and foreign key is AddressId field from employee

Comment: Provide the structures as complete SHOW CREATE TABLE output, not as approximate description.

Comment: *The record from Address Table doesn't gets deleted when I delete Employee Table records.* I think that your FOREIGN KEY is defined partially and does not contain correct ON DELETE cascade action. If it is defined correctly then dependent rows should be deleted automatically when main row is deleted.

Comment: There is no parent child relationship , if there was address would have a FK pointing to employee. You need to delete address in code or build a trigger in mysql to do so automatically on deletion of employee. As is if there is an on delete cascade in the FK in employee then employee will be deleted when address is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `ON DELETE CASCADE` feature, which will indicates to MySQL that a record should be deleted when its "parent" record (in another table) is deleted.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE address (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Details VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    State VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE employee (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    AddressId INT NOT NULL,
    Code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (AddressId)
        REFERENCES address (Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```